# flex-wrap elements in pairs

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with 4 inner divs containing images and text. the flexbox is allowed to wrap with: `flex-wrap: wrap`

in a normal laptop screen the items are in one row like:

item item item item,

when the window is scaled down, the last flex element goes down in a new row like:

item item item 
item

this way I have 3 items in the first row, and 1 in the second.

What I need is that the row to break only in pairs. to not have 3 in a row, and 1 in a new row, just all 4 in a row, or 2 / 2 in a row.

I also need that the items to shrink a bit, but I found a workaround for it.

```
<div class = "flex">

    <div class = "f4">
        <a href = "...">
            <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </a>
        <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>

    <div class = "f4">
        <a href = "...">
            <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </a>
        <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>

    <div class = "f4">
        <a href = "...">
            <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </a>
        <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>

    <div class = "f4">
        <a href = "...">
            <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </a>
        <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.f4 {
    flex-basis: 300px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 8px;
}
.f4 img {
    max-width: 330px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

EDIT:

I let the items to shrink until the original size does not fit 3 times, this way I do not have to add extra wrapper.

```
.f4 {
    flex-basis: 243.5px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 330px;
    margin: 8px;
}
.f4 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1038px) {
    .f4 {
        flex-basis: 330px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use mediaqueries to handle smaller resolutions

Comment: Why not have two divs?
These two divs will contain two inner divs each.

Comment: @UtsavPatel this idea not so useful for generating lists - That the list length is dynamic ( (Blog page list for example)

Comment: I just hope when we get `text-align: justify-all;` (still experimental) it could be used to solve this problem. It would be text based, but it could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No way** to auto solve this for all cases (Besides extra wrappers for **[1-2]** and **[3-4]**).

**"Extra wrapper"** not useful for generates lists (When the length of the list is dynamic - **blog page list** for example).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

**The most basic way to solve this is by media Q:**

Your layout is:
`[25%]` `[25%]` `[25%]` `[25%]`
And on smaller screens: `50%` `50%` - This is why media queries are so useful.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  /* align card  */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #e1f7ff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .col{
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="flex">
  <div class="col">col 1</div>
  <div class="col">col 2</div>
  <div class="col">col 3</div>
  <div class="col">col 4</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy trick you can do is to make a wrapper along with those 2 `flex`:

Play around with [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/axo0h1c7/29/) for more clarity.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Row {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.f4 {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 8px;
}

.f4 img {
  max-width: 330px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="Row">
    <div class="f4">
      <a href="...">
        <img ... width="330" height="247">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </a>
      <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>

    <div class="f4">
      <a href="...">
        <img ... width="330" height="247">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </a>
      <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Row">
    <div class="f4">
      <a href="...">
        <img ... width="330" height="247">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </a>
      <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>

    <div class="f4">
      <a href="...">
        <img ... width="330" height="247">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </a>
      <p>the excertp ... </p>
    </div>
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: In your code, the output is always 2 in a row (He asked for [item item item item] on desktop.

Comment: @EzraSiton it is not, check this : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/axo0h1c7/29/ or you can expand the result as full screen, that will show you 4 items in single row.

Comment: I click the "full page" on your code snippet. Ok. It's better if you improve the code for future users (The idea of grids is always to fill up the available space - use %).

Answer (score 1):

> **Hope this will satisfy your ans**

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.f {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
}
.f4 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 8px;
}
.f4 img {
    max-width: 330px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class = "flex">

    <div class = "f">
        <div class = "f4">
            <a href = "...">
                <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </a>
            <p>the excertp ... </p>
        </div>

        <div class = "f4">
            <a href = "...">
                <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </a>
            <p>the excertp ... </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "f">
        <div class = "f4">
            <a href = "...">
                <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </a>
            <p>the excertp ... </p>
        </div>

        <div class = "f4">
            <a href = "...">
                <img ... width = "330" height = "247" >
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </a>
            <p>the excertp ... </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but need an extra wrapper as Ezra wrote, otherways the f4 is too large

Comment: According to @Erza, depending on content of each item somehow it can be broken in 3:1... your desired ans can't be come possibly

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link. also you can do one thing use `flex-basic:auto` instead of fixed width and use media queries for devices

https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#align-self